# Show some fields on a calendar based on checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar

does anyone know how I can edit a SP Calendar list so that certain fields will disappear and be emptied depending on a checkbox? There are a couple of fields that only make sense when the box is checked and they should be required when it is checked and hidden when not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You should create a custom content type based on Event Item. Then you should create custom Add & Edit form to handle hide/show fields.

**Option 2**

Using SharePoint Designer you can edit `editform.aspx` and add JavaScript code which does the show/hide based on checkbox selection